# My Blackberry 10 Cascades (C++, Qt & QML) sample app is crashing on startup with the following error

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10

I am trying to make a sample Blackberry 10 Cascades app in C++, Qt, & QML in the QNX Momentics IDE, and run it in the Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator. When I start running it, I get the following error messages:

ApplicationPrivate::declarativeEngine: ERROR called from non-UI thread QThread(0x8067e48) 
ApplicationPrivate::declarativeEngine: Method called from non-UI thread

I have tried googling those error messages - but I only find a few links that actually apply to my situation - and the solutions for those problems don't seem to apply to me.

I know it's got something to do with me trying to call different classes from different qml documents.  (Which is something I was having trouble with before - which is why I made this sample app in the first place - to see if I could figure out how to call different classes from different qml documents).

Here is the code of my sample app. There are 7 files (`main.qml`, `main.cpp`, `app.cpp`, `app.hpp`, `Page2.cpp`, `Page2.h`, `Page2.qml`).  I would much appreciate if anyone could help me solve this - because I am not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

(I have taken out `main.cpp` & reduced the code from the other 6 files to what I think are the key parts to this problem).

I know the problem has something to do with my `Page2` class and the `Page2.qml` file.

(I think the problem is that there is something I have to do to be able to call qt code from more than one qml files - and I just don't know what that is).

`main.qml`:

---

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

//-- create one page with a label and text
Page {
    content: Container {
        Button {
            text: "Page 2"
            onClicked: app.goToPage2
        }
    }
}
```

---

from `app.cpp`

---

```
App::App()
{
    qmlRegisterType<App>("GDLiteBB", 1, 0, "app");
    qmlRegisterType<Page2>("GDLiteBB", 1, 0, "Page2");

    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("main.qml");
    qml->setContextProperty("app", this);

    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();
    Application::setScene(root);
}

void App::goToPage2() {
    Page2::getInstance();
}
```

---

from `app.hpp`

---

```
class App : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    App();

    Q_INVOKABLE void goToPage2();
};
```

---

`Page2.cpp`

---

```
QmlDocument * Page2::qml_ = QmlDocument::create("Page2.qml");
AbstractPane * Page2::root_ = qml_->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();
Label * Page2::label_ = root_->findChild<Label *>("label");

Page2::Page2() : QObject() {
    ++count_;
    page2_ = this;
    qml_->setContextProperty("Page2", this);
    Application::setScene(root_);
}

Page2 *Page2::getInstance() {
    return page2_ ? page2_ : new Page2();
}

void Page2::setLabel() {
    label_->setText("This is page 2");
}
```

---

`Page2.h`

---

```
class Page2 : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    static Page2 *page2_;
    static unsigned int count_;

    static bb::cascades::QmlDocument *qml_;
    static bb::cascades::AbstractPane *root_;
    static bb::cascades::Label *label_;

    Page2();
public:
    static Page2 *getInstance();
    virtual ~Page2();

    Q_INVOKABLE void setLabel();
};
```

---

`Page2.qml`

---

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import GDLiteBB 1.0

Page {
    content: Container {
        Button {
            text: "Set Label"
            onClicked: Page2.setLabel()
        }
        Label {
            objectName: "Label"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to simplify your code until either the error goes away, or it's a minimal example that still reproduces your problem. Nobody here will want to read all the code sections that are irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: Mic_e => I have taken out main.cpp & reduced the code from the other 6 files to what I think are the key parts to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is these lines:

```
QmlDocument * Page2::qml_ = QmlDocument::create("Page2.qml");
AbstractPane * Page2::root_ = qml_->createRootNode<AbstractPane>();
Label * Page2::label_ = root_->findChild<Label *>("label");
```

These objects are being created as soon as the application code loads into memory, which means that it's happening before the event loop starts in `main()`. All classes that inherit from QObject need to be created after the event loop starts and destroyed before the event loop ends.